# Delphi5 Virtual TreeView wanted

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

Does anyone happen to have a copy of the Virtual TreeView that is Delphi5 compatible? Or does anyone know where it can be downloaded from?

Thanks in advance to any responses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the official site of virtual treeview creator : http://www.soft-gems.net/

just follow the link "**All Downloads**"

Virtual treeview 4.5.2 is compatible with Delphi 5

Comment: Thanks Damien. We have got the latest version working in Delphi 5 as well, with some relatively easy adjustments. We will probably use 4.5.2 though.